# Tell the binary where to look for BUILT library

Tags: centos7, glibc

I have a binary that requires glibc-2.18 installed, but the newest I can get using `yum` is 2.17. What I would want to accomplish is to test my binary with only a **built** glibc-2.18 (not installed, from what I've read it's a bad idea to do it manually). I read multiple articles regarding the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and how to set it, but most of them were either incomplete for me to follow through or I get an error, such as `sed: relocation error`.

As for glibc and how I built it: downloaded the version, extracted, made `/build` folder inside the extracted folder, and from it, ran `../configure --prefix=/usr`. Finally, in the same folder, `make`.

Could someone provide step-by-step instructions on how to run my binary with the built library ?

Answer (score 0):

> What I would want to accomplish is to test my binary with only a built glibc-2.18 (not installed, from what I've read it's a bad idea to do it manually).

This is what GLIBC itself does when you run `make check`:

```
/build/elf/ld.so --library-path /build:/build/elf:/build/math:/build/nptl:... /path/to/binary
```

Explanation: run `ld.so` from `/build` and ask it to load other parts of GLIBC from the `/build` and its subdirectories.

This works for most programs, but there is a certain class of programs that wouldn't work when invoked this way. One example in the latter category is a program that `execve()`s itself.

Comment: is specifying the full path of the `/build` folder for the --library-path enough or do I need to list all the each folder required specifically like in your make check example ? I used `/build/elf/ld.so --library-path /abosulte/path/to/build/ /path/to/binary` and got  `relocation error: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: symbol __h_errno, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference`

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the binary with `-Wl,-rpath`, as explained in the [glibc testing instructions](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location). So if glibc 2.18 is installed under `/opt/gnu/glibc-2.18`, the linker invocation could look like this:

```
gcc -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/gnu/glibc-2.18/lib64/ld-2.18.so \
  -Wl,-rpath=/opt/gnu/glibc-2.18/lib64 -L/opt/gnu/glibc-2.18/lib64
```